# how to fixe django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser to User

Tags: python, django, django-users

Hi everyone I'm making ecommerce web project and I try to associate user to carts but i have problem with `is_authenticated()` method when the user is login it's work but it's is logout it's show this error `"ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x0000018AD88052B0>>": "cart.user" must be a "User" instance""`

```
model.py
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            new_obj = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated() and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj = cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
            new_obj = True
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        return cart_obj, new_obj
```

I expected to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try ..

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
```

in place of

```
request.user.is_authenticated()
```

Comment: This gives error: "bool object is not callable"